# Running in Da Nang, Vietnam

Tags: vietnam, outdoor-activities

I will be visiting Da Nang, Vietnam for business in a week. I'm heavily addicted to running and trail running in particular. I've never visited Vietnam before. Throughout the week I will have to run either early in the morning or in the evening. Considering the weather that wouldn't be a bad idea anyway.

How would a foreigner go about running in Da Nang?
Is it safe?
Are there some nice routes?
Is there anything I need to think about that I typically wouldn't think about as a European?

For example: I'm thinking about running to Hoy An, having dinner/lunch there and either taking a taxi back or running back, depending on how I feel afterwards.

Would that be a good idea?

Comment: The weather will be very hot and humid, which is uncommon in Europe. Drink more water.

Answer (score 9):

Writing this sat in Da Nang airport. You're going to find the heat and sun difficult. Plenty of water (take some cash and you'll be able to buy bottles along your route) and sun cream required. In terms of risk of being attacked you'll be fine I think, but the road often lack footpaths and where they do exist they are often filled with scooters/chairs/food stands. It looked like there were some off road riverside paths near Hoi An.

Comment: I just realised I never replied to this answer and StackExchange reminded me that it's a question I once asked. Your answer was completely correct.

I started a run from Da Nang, early in the morning, thinking I could manage to run about 15 km with just a single bottle of water. Immediately after leaving the hotel, taxi drivers started calling me crazy for running in this heat. After about 2 km, my bottle of water was already empty. The heat and humidity overwhelmed me. Long story short: I bought about 4 liters of water, and ran only 7 km instead of 15. :-)

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Did you find anywhere good to run?

Comment: Not really. The round I ran was through the city center, over the river and back. Other times I used the treadmill at the hotel.

Answer (score 7):

Heat and humidity aside, the promenade alongside China Beach in Da Nang is probably one of the easiest places to run in Vietnam. Motorbikes tend to be kept off it, something that can't even be said for the parks in Hanoi! Even when it peters out in parts at the north end of the beach, the road is relatively wide and relatively quiet. It's shaded in places, and it's a few km long.

As you leave the city to the south, there is a footpath - at least some of the way - although there are definitely sections where running on the road is required. The road between Da Nang and Hoi An is fast and busy.

Your main risks are getting clipped by a motorbike or bus, and dehydration. To avoid the former, run as close to the side as you can, and bear in mind that no-one will give way to you - even when they're turning into or out of a side-road. To avoid the latter, wear a hat and drink water. There are fewer shops on the main road (it's mostly top end resorts), so it's best to carry some.

If you do decide to run down the main road, the advantage of the numerous top end resorts will be taxis in the event that you get too hot and give up. You may be able to pop into one to pick up a taxi from a rank, but more than likely there will be a handful parked outside it too.